# Is there any Linux Alternatives to Cinebench and AIDA64?

Tags: windows, system-monitor, benchmarks

I recently started migrating from Windows 10 to Ubuntu version 20.04. And even though everything is running smoothly, I wish I could use applications such as *AIDA 64* or *Cinebench* to both check and benchmark my hardware. Of course I could use a compatibility layer such as *Proton*, but I do not want to deal with the unnecessary complications that comes when using a windows application on a Linux system. So, **is there any Linux alternatives that act similar to *AIDA 64* and *Cinebench*?**

Comment: [HardInfo](https://itsfoss.com/hardinfo/) can run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Phoronix Test Suite is a benchmark management tool with something like 200+ benchmarks available to it.

Also, Unigine benchmarks have native linux ports, though they are gpu BMs, not CPU like Cinebench.